# How can I filter a nested object with dynamic filters using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following data:

```
 properties: {
  '2': [
    {
      id: "2015-1160312",
      date: "2015-01-23",
      number: 1,
      nature: "Sell",
      value: 310000,
      address_number: 10,
      adresse_code: "ST LINCOLN",
      ZIPCODE: "CO80216",
      number_rooms: 2}
      ],
  '4': [
    {
      id: "2015-1160312",
      date: "2015-01-23",
      nature_mutation: "Sell",
      value: 450000,
      address_number: 15,
      adresse_code: "ST HOOHER",
      ZIPCODE: "CO45216",
      number_rooms: 4
   }
      ]
    }
```

And I have a filter object, that is created dynamically:

```
let selectedFilters = {1,2,3};
```

I want to filter the properties where the "number_rooms" corresponds to the selectedFilters items.
In the example, I should only get the first item

Comment: `Object.values(properties).filter(ch => selectedFilters.includes(ch.number_rooms))` =)

Comment: `selectedFilters` is an invalid structure. Also strange that each of the values inside `properties` is an array. Are you the one creating these structures?

Comment: Yes I am, I created this structure, it works for most of my code

Comment: Probably more practical if `properties` was a single array. What are the keys `"2"` and `"4"` used for?

Comment: I use `"2"` and `"4"`  to group the `properties` value by `number_rooms`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `properties` is already grouped by `number_rooms` so that means you don't need to filter, just iterating over `selectedFilters` keys will help. Something like -

```
Object.keys(selectedFilters).forEach(k=> {
   // properties[k] if exists -> will give you required data
})
```